# MS Project C# programmatically adding Budget

Tags: c#, office-interop, ms-project

I am currently creating a project using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject` reference in C#. I need to add budget to the project in the `ProjectSummaryTask` after I have added the resource using the following code, but I get an error.

```
resourceBudget = resource2.Add("budget");
resourceBudget.Type = PjResourceTypes.pjResourceTypeCost;
resourceBudget.Budget = true;
maintask =project.ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask;
maintask.ResourceNames = resourceBudget.Name;

maintask.BudgetCost = 20000;
```

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The argument value is not valid.'

In the `maintask.BudgetCost` section. Would any body give an idea on how to add the budget?

Comment: In your debugger, what is the value and type of `maintask.BudgetCost` immediately before you set it? The documentation says it's a COM Variant, so assigning an `Int32` value should work, but I wonder if something else is amiss.

Comment: BudgetCost is a calculated field. [See documentation.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/budget-cost-fields-debac6b2-48fb-4314-b1a5-8a5f0979f6cb)

Comment: Rachel you are right that is a calculated value, i looked at the documentation and I had to use the resource value as such,  
            MSProject.Assignments assignments = null;         
            assignments = maintask.Assignments;
            assignments[1].BudgetCost = 15000;